# Are or is your arm and neck feeling better?

Tags: grammaticality

I'm inquiring about someone's arm and neck so technically plural and I'm siding with are as in, "Are your arm and neck feeling better?" versus is (singular) however would there be a more formal way of inquiring without the question becoming too ambiguous?

Comment: Either could be used.  "Is" implies that "arm and neck" are being treated as a single concern, which might be the case if, eg, the problem involves a tendon connecting the two.  "Are" would refer to the more general case were both the arm and neck were of concern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [The Chicago Manual of Style](http://www.chicagomanualofstyle.org/16/ch05/ch05_sec131.html)

> 5.131Agreement in person and number
>   A finite verb agrees with its subject in person and number. When a verb has two or more subjects connected by and, it agrees with them jointly and is plural {Socrates and Plato were wise}. When a verb has two or more singular subjects connected by or or nor, it is singular {Jill or Jan is prepared to speak} {neither Bob nor John has learned his lesson}. When the subject is a collective noun conveying the idea of unity or multitude, the verb is singular {the nation is powerful}. When the subject is a collective noun conveying the idea of plurality, the verb is plural {the faculty were divided in their sentiments}.

Here if you mean them separately, i.e., you want to know about each of the arm and the neck individually, use the plural. If you want to know about a single injury to the arm and neck, use the singular.

Answer (score 0):

How about "How are your arm and your neck?  Are they better?"

Comment: That doesn’t answer the question - it picks ‘are’ but doesn’t explain why.